# Save the Configuration of a Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Does Jackson provide a means of saving the configuration of an `ObjectMapper` and then recreating it from this saved information?

In my particular case, I need to be able to record along with some data what modules were in use by the mapper when the data was written so that the same modules can be loaded for deserialization.

## Update

The reason for this is the need to store some data with the sequence of transformations that was applied to create that data.  All of these transformations implement a known interface, but otherwise nothing is known about them and many different ones will be implemented by users. When serializing, it may be necessary to load modules in order to serialize some of the transformations.  We'd like to be able to deserialize these transformations later in order to transform new data in the same way as the existing data, but without knowing what modules were loaded into the ObjectMapper, deserialization may fail.

Comment: At first glance, this kind of seems like bad design. Can you give us an example?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: I don't think this is doable out of the box, then (with updates). ObjectMapper does not even (by default) keep track of modules that have registered (no back-refs to avoid unintentional memory retention). So you would probably need to build your own configuration that keeps track of necessary information, to produce mapper instances, serialize/deserialize configuration.

Comment: @StaxMan: Thanks for your response. Since for my purposes I only need to track modules, I basically did eactly what you suggest, which wasn't very difficult for my limited needs.  If you'd like to make your comment an answers, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectMapper` is actually `java.io.Serializable`, if you REALLY want to do this. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but it is possible. It is used by some on Android, to reduce cost of re-creating mapper instances (due to the way Dalvik swaps out apps).

Comment: Are all its fields `Serializable`?

Comment: @StaxMan: thanks very much for your response.  I'm concerned that if its serialized form is not guaranteed to be stable across time, that can be a problem. (For example, Guava classes are mostly serializable, but deserialization of an object serialized from an older Guava version in a newer Guava version can fail).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, it has been tested to be fully (de)serializable, including all transitive dependencies.

Comment: @rmg Yes, this is a valid concern of course, for anything longer than storing it across restarts and/or using for caching (where you can just drop old copy if reading back fails).